# Pandas most efficient way to do a multicolumn sort if the order of the first column doesn't matter

Tags: python, pandas, performance, sorting

I have a DataFrame with around 300 million rows and two columns. I need to sort the second column, while keeping together all rows that have the same value in the first column, but the order of the first column doesn't matter.

If I started with:

```
 |ID  |Date
0|DEF |2000-01-01
1|ABC |2000-01-01
2|DEF |2000-02-01
3|ABC |2000-02-01
```

I need to end up with either:

```
 |ID  |Date
0|DEF |2000-01-01
2|DEF |2000-02-01
1|ABC |2000-01-01
3|ABC |2000-02-01
```

or

```
 |ID  |Date
1|ABC |2000-01-01
3|ABC |2000-02-01
0|DEF |2000-01-01
2|DEF |2000-02-01
```

But it doesn't matter if I get the first or the second. Running

```
df.sort_values(by=["ID", "Date"])
```

on the full set of data takes about 8 minutes, but a part of that time is spent making sure the ID column is in the right order, which doesn't matter to me. The only way I could think to sort Date within groups of ID without sorting ID is

```
df.groupby("ID", sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by=["Date"])
```

But the groupby code takes significantly longer to run than just sorting the ID column. On a smaller sample of 10,000,000 rows the groupby sort takes over 10 minutes compared to 17.6 seconds for the two-column sort.

Is there a clever way to sort the second column within groups of the first that would be more efficient than just sorting both columns, or is the two-column sort the fastest I'm going to get?

Comment: i dont think your sample data quite captures what you are after; it doesnt capture the part where you ensure ID is in the right order.

Comment: I never want to ensure ID is in the right order. ID can be in any order, and I don't want to be spending time sorting that column, but I can't sort only on date or else similar IDs wouldn't be grouped together.

Comment: maybe make the ID column a categorical and then sort. 300 million rows is significant though, so not sure what else you can do here. `pydatatable` might be faster; it does not have as many features as Pandas though, and I havent tested on 300m rows to be sure

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I work for [bodo.ai](https://bodo.ai)

I tried your code with Bodo, and here's how it worked out for me.

Generated some data first and stored it in a [parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) file (I tested with two dataframe sizes, 1m and 100m rows):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



def gen_data(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        "Date" : np.repeat(pd.date_range("2013-01-03", periods=1000), n),
        "id" : np.random.choice(['ABC','DEF','GHI'], n * 1000)
        }
        )
    df.to_parquet("pd_example"+str(n)+".pq", row_group_size=100000)

gen_data(100000)
```

Then I added a Bodo JIT decorator to your code, printed out the head and tail to see what that looks like and added some timers to see how much time Bodo takes.

```py
import bodo
import time

@bodo.jit
def get_output(input_file):

    # add timer here to start timing after compilation
    t1 = time.time()

    df = pd.read_parquet(input_file)
    # your original code
    df1 = df.sort_values(by=["id", "Date"]) 

    print("time taken:",time.time()-t1)
    print(df1.head(10), df1.tail(10)) 

    return df1
```

Bodo uses [MPI](https://hpc-wiki.info/hpc/MPI) to parallelize Pandas code, so I was also able to run this code on 4 cores. Here are my results on a 2020 Macbook Pro:

| Rows | Cores | Time Taken |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1m | 1 | 3.22s |
| 1m | 4 | 0.97s |
| 10m | 1 | 41s |
| 10m | 4 | 12.5s |

Bodo is available as a [conda install](https://docs.bodo.ai/latest/source/installation_and_setup/install.html) and free to use on up to 4 cores.